# Why is this javascript inserting two spinner images?

Tags: javascript

```
// javascript for ajax pagination//

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // the element in which we will observe all clicks and capture
  // ones originating from pagination links
  var container = $(document.body)

  if (container) {
    var img = new Image
    img.src = '/images/spinner.gif'

    function createSpinner() {
      return new Element('img', { src: img.src, 'class': 'spinner' })
    }

    container.observe('click', function(e) {
      var el = e.element()
      if (el.match('.pagination a')) {
        el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner())
        new Ajax.Request(el.href, { method: 'get' })
        e.stop()
      }
    })
 }
})
```

Why is this script inserting two spinner images?

here is the html

```
 <div style="margin-top:25px;">
      <div class="pagination ajax">
           <span class="disabled prev_page">&laquo; Previous</span> 
           <span class="current">1</span> 
           <a href="/posts?page=2" rel="next">2</a> 
           <a href="/posts?page=3">3</a> 
           <a href="/posts?page=2" class="next_page" rel="next">Next &raquo;</a>
      </div>
      <br style="clear:both;"/>
 </div>
```

Comment: What JavaScript framework are you using? What happened to all your semicolons? You should be creating the image like this: `var img = new Image();` How about showing some markup?

Comment: prototype. I didn't write it.

Comment: My eyes!! Run your javascript code through http://www.jslint.com/ and fix all errors.

Comment: yeah, I'm not a big javascript fan although if I had a language to really be good at that would be it. I seriously have not js skills so I cannot do that.

Comment: @Sam: I'm sorry if I was too sarcastic. Look at the my answer below, where you find the fixed version of your javascript code. It probably don't fix your problem, but at least makes it more legal. What environment are you using when developing? Firefox + firebug? Are you sure the event is fired only once?

Comment: I copy/pasted the code you provided, and each click of a link only inserted one spinner image. Exact code is at http://pastebin.com/wuHT7apD, using Prototype 1.6. Tested on Chrome 6, FF4 beta 6, Opera 10.6, an IE 9 beta. Do you have a link where we can see the problem in action? Are you leaving out code/html thats in in the actual problematic page? Is this only happening with a specific browser? The information you've given doesn't reproduce your problem, so no one can help you yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the javascript through jslint and fixed all errors but `new Ajax`. I moved the `createSpinner`-function since it's not advisable to define it inside a block. Also the declaration of `img` was moved, semicolons added, and line-breaks to make the code more readable. (I have not tested the code, just "beautified" it)

```
document.observe(
  "dom:loaded",
  function() {
    var img;
    function createSpinner() {
      return new Element('img', { src: img.src, 'class': 'spinner' });
    }

    // the element in which we will observe all clicks and capture
    // ones originating from pagination links
    var container = $(document.body);

    if (container) {
      img = new Image( );
      img.src = '/images/spinner.gif';

      container.observe(
        'click',
        function(e) {
          var el = e.element();
          if (el.match('.pagination a')) {
            el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner());
            new Ajax.Request(el.href, { method: 'get' });
            e.stop();
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Just to be sure, its *perfectly* "legal" to declare a JS function within a block. However just like a var declaration, the function scope is the entire containing function, but unlike var, the function is defined regardless.

Comment: @Angoiosperm: It executes, but it's confusing: `function load() { var container=1; if (container) { function createSpinner() { alert("me");} } createSpinner(); }` Can we agree that it's confusing and should be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Are there two elements with class=pagination?

Comment: This should be a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: @patrick, I agree, but I also see how it could be a simple gotcha answer

Comment: @patrick - thanks, point taken.  But I was looking for the gotcha, considering there was no markup to look at.

Answer (score 1):

try to do this changes :

// javascript for ajax pagination//

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // the element in which we will observe all clicks and capture
  // ones originating from pagination links
  var container = $(document.body)

if (container) {
    var img = new Image
    img.src = '/images/spinner.gif'

```
var createSpinner() = function { 
  return new Element('img', { src: img.src, 'class': 'spinner' });
}

container.observe('click', function(e) {
  var el = e.element()
  if (el.match('.pagination a')) {
    el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner);
    new Ajax.Request(el.href, { 
      method: 'get',
      success: function(){ el.up('.pagination').find('img.spinner').remove(); }
    });
    e.stop()
  }
});
```

}
});

Comment: please be more specific. Please take the original file and replace/change what you believe to be the problem.

Comment: @Sam, Patrick Ferreira - The function creation would give a syntax error. If you were intending `var createSpinner = function()`, then it would be functionally equivalent to the question. And doing `el.up('.pagination').insert(createSpinner);` would be to attempt to insert the function itself, not the return value from calling the function.